# JSON checker to avoid com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee

I'm getting many JSON objects through a web service and at times the json object is malformed.

I wanted to check the if the json is valid before processing it.

So i worte

```
JsonElement jsonData = parser.parse(attacheddataattribute);
if(jsonData.isJsonObject()) 
                {
//then only process
}
```

Not also its throwing a
    com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated string at line 1 column 8432 at the parse method.

Is there any implemenation available to check for the JSON's validity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's your validation. No need to call any service.

If the method is throwing the `MalformedJsonException` it's a malformed JSON.

If you want you can wrap it in a method like

```
public boolean isValidJson(String json) {
    try {
        // parse json
        return true;
    } catch(MalformedJsonException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Man, that's the best solution I guess.

Comment: But there is a compliation issue "Unreachable catch block for MalformedJsonException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body"

Comment: It means that the method that you're using to parse the json cannot cause the exception. Did you add your parse() method?

Answer (score 0):

I also had the MalformedJsonException crash but in my case I needed to add a catch block with Throwable:

```
    fun jsonToList(value: String?): MutableList<String> {
        var objects: Array<String> = emptyArray()
        try {
            objects = Gson().fromJson(value, Array<String>::class.java)
        }catch (t: Throwable){

        }finally {
            return objects.toMutableList()
        }
    }
```